# How do I prove the tracing part in a ring signature model?

Tags: signature, traitor-tracing

I have a question about the article “efficient and multi-level privacy-preserving communication protocol for VANET” by H. Xiong et al.

I need the ID of malicious vehicle, but I could not prove how I can get its public key from the equation given in the part of OBU fast tracing on page 5.

How do I prove that the equation in section 3.4 is correct?

Page 4:

> [image: page 4]

Page 5:

> [image: page 5]